# SWF to PDF conversion

Tags: command-line, pdf, swf

Are there any tools for converting SWF to PDF? I have a bunch of SWF files (to be ripped from the web) and I'd like to group them into single PDF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](http://www.romeilsandhu.com/convert-swf-to-pdf/) is a nice tutorial how to do that using a combination of [swftools](http://www.swftools.org/) and imageMagic.

Basically, use `swfrender` to convert the SWF to PNG, then `convert` to convert PNG to PDF.

Comment: Is there a proper deb package for swftools? It seems that apt can't find it and other tutorials suggest compiling from the source.

Comment: I have no idea, (I have compiled them from source, it's fairly easy).  but [here](http://linuxappfinder.com/package/swftools) I found some debs. HTH

Comment: @Philomath Ouch! Now "Here" link is broken.